# DNSCrypt-proxy: This certificate looks valid

Tags: certificates, dns, ecc, dnssec

I have just installed `dnscrypt-proxy` and `dnsmasq` with `DNSSEC` but I get a strange message in the logfile from `dnscrypt-proxy`.

```
[INFO] + DNS Security Extensions are supported
[INFO] - [dnscrypt.eu-dk] does not support Namecoin domains
[INFO] + Provider supposedly doesn't keep logs
[NOTICE] Starting dnscrypt-proxy 1.6.0
[INFO] Generating a new session key pair
[INFO] Done
[INFO] Server certificate #808464433 received
[INFO] This certificate looks valid
[INFO] Chosen certificate #808464433 is valid from [2015-09-11] to [2016-09-10]
[INFO] Server key fingerprint is 164E:1AD6:4356:777D:2019:F2F9:D389:2DDB:BC75:8AF0:9172:8E0C:A874:10C7:3BE8:423B
```

The part that I think is suspicious, is this:

```
[INFO] This certificate looks valid
```

It sounds like the `dnscrypt-proxy` have doubts about how valid the certificate is. What happens to the absolute state of valid? Either it is a valid certificate or not.

Have I done something wrong with the configuration?

Configuration file (Resolver part):

```
DNSCRYPT_PROXY_PROVIDER_KEY=3748:5585:E3B9:D088:FD25:AD36:B037:01F5:520C:D648:9E9A:DD52:1457:4955:9F0A:9955
DNSCRYPT_PROXY_PROVIDER_NAME=2.dnscrypt-cert.resolver2.dnscrypt.eu 
DNSCRYPT_PROXY_RESOLVER_ADDRESS=77.66.84.233:443
DNSCRYPT_PROXY_RESOLVER_NAME=dnscrypt.eu-dk
```

init.d script (start part):

```
if start_daemon -p "${DNSCRYPT_PROXY_PIDFILE}" ${DNSCRYPT_PROXY_BIN} \
    --pidfile "${DNSCRYPT_PROXY_PIDFILE}" \
    --daemonize \
    --ephemeral-keys \
    --user="${DNSCRYPT_PROXY_USER}" \
    --local-address="${DNSCRYPT_PROXY_LOCAL_ADDRESS}" \
    --provider-key="${DNSCRYPT_PROXY_PROVIDER_KEY}" \
    --provider-name="${DNSCRYPT_PROXY_PROVIDER_NAME}" \
    --resolver-name="${DNSCRYPT_PROXY_RESOLVER_NAME}" \
    --resolver-address="${DNSCRYPT_PROXY_RESOLVER_ADDRESS}" \
    --logfile="${DNSCRYPT_PROXY_LOG_FILE}" \
    $DNSCRYPT_PROXY_OPTIONS; then
```

The internal dataflow is as follow:

```
| DNS Client -> DNSMasq (+ DNSSEC) -> DNSCrypt-proxy | -> | LAN/Internet |
+----------------------------------------------------+----+--------------+
|                    Internal                        |    |    Network   |
```

Answer (score 3):

It is valid.

See [this change](https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-proxy/commit/c35c8c52ac45f044e1f360dc82df1d13e533a780) in the developement tree.

That said, your configuration should be simplified. When using a predefined resolver, all you need is the resolver name:

`DNSCRYPT_PROXY_RESOLVER_NAME=dnscrypt.eu-dk`

It doesn't make any sense to provide the name of a predefined resolver and then manually override everything. Worse, it will break if the certificate parameters change.

Just remove `DNSCRYPT_PROXY_PROVIDER_KEY`, `DNSCRYPT_PROXY_PROVIDER_NAME` and
`DNSCRYPT_PROXY_RESOLVER_ADDRESS`. These are only useful when you are running your own DNSCrypt server.